# PINCache objectForKey returning NSCoding and can't casting it

Tags: ios, swift, casting, exc-bad-access, nscoding

I'm using PINCache (https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache) to cache some objects into my app. So, using objC it is perfect, but when I wanna cast with swift I had `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

When I call `objectForKey`

`- (id <NSCoding>)objectForKey:(NSString *)key;`

And I have nothing cached for that key, but Swift understand that the object is an NSConding. So, if I have values into a key, I have no problems.

So, how can I cast this NSCoding result and compare with nil value. I only need to know if the object return from PINCache is nil (never cached).

I've already tried:

```
private func setupTrucks() {
    let trucksCached: AnyObject? = PINDiskCache.sharedCache().objectForKey(TruckCache.key)
    if let _truck = trucksCached as? [Truck] { //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
        print(_truck)
    }
}

private func setupTrucks() {
    let trucksCached = PINDiskCache.sharedCache().objectForKey(TruckCache.key) as [Truck] //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    if trucksCached.count > 0 {
        print(_truck)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like PINCache is not defining the return types of the synchronous `objectForKey:` methods as `__nullable`. Without that Swift doesn't know that the return type is optional.

I submitted a PR, which has already been accepted, that should fix the problem.  You should now be able to do something like:

```
let trucksCached: AnyObject? = PINDiskCache.sharedCache().objectForKey("truck_key")
if let _truck = trucksCached as? Truck {
    print(_truck)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the PR :) Now I can do: `let truckCached = PINDiskCache.sharedCache().objectForKey(TruckCache.key) as? [Truck] ?? [Truck]()`